# render_template can't find template, send_file can

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

In some cases I want to render a template and in others I want to serve the template file. I passed the same path to `render_template` and `send_file`, but only `send_file` worked.

```
resp = render_template('templates/index.html')
resp = send_file('templates/index.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template paths are relative to the templates root. `send_file` paths are relative to the app root.

```
render_template('file.html')
send_file('templates/file.html')
```

---

Aside, template paths aren't actually file system paths, they just happen to look like them in the default Flask case. So "templates root" really means, "lookup paths for the template loader" not "the templates folder".